# Use the annihilator method and find the general solution of $y''-3y'+2y=4\sin^3(3x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use the annihilator method and find the general solution of

$$y''-3y'+2y=4\sin^3(3x)$$
$$m^2-3m+2=0$$
$$(m-1)(m-2)=0$$
$$m=1,m=2$$
$$y_c=c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}$$

Wich is the annihilator of $4\sin^3(3x)$?

Comment: $4sen^3(3x)$? Is that supposed to be $4\sin^3(3x)?$

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change it, sorry.

Comment: (You can use `$\sin$` to get the nice-looking $\sin$ operator.)

Comment: There's an example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_method), and a nifty table to help you out. Try using that, then edit your question to show us what you've tried wrt the annihilator method if you can't get to the answer.

Comment: $\sin^3$ isn't in Wikipedia's table, but using the fact that $\sin a = -\frac{i}{2}(e^{ia}-e^{-ia})$...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try using

$$4\sin^3(3x) = 3 \sin (3 x)-\sin (9 x)$$

Using the [*Annihilator Method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_method), this will lead to the result $y(x) = y_h(x)+ y_p(x)$

$$y(x) = c_1 e^x+c_2 e^{2 x}+\dfrac{27}{130} \cos (3 x)-\dfrac{21}{130} \sin (3 x)-\dfrac{27 }{6970}\cos (9 x)+\dfrac{79 }{6970}\sin (9 x)$$

Comment: @U134543: Are you really using the Annihilator Method in what you posted? You are supposed to use the method to solve the entire problem.